# Avoid landing page redirects - force www and https

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to forward non-www to www and forward http to https.  I have tried other solutions, the only code I can get to work is below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

**UPDATED:**
(Like @Croises stated) - *Redirect www first then https*

```
RewriteEngine on
### redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
### redirect non-http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Google page speed (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) is telling me "Your page has 2 redirects."  Is there a way to combine www and https into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single rule for both redirects:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this change

Comment: Non-www isn't forwarding with the above?

Comment: Are you sure? Exact same rule on my Apache redirects `http://www.domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com` Just make sure this is very first rule and there is no other conflicting rule.

Comment: Any thing wrong with the answer? I thought requirement was to avoid 2 redirects

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite domain before https:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```